# webpack throw new TypeError('Path must be a string. Received ' +

Tags: npm, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have a problem, when i use webpack from cmd (npm start).
It throw a error.But yesterday do not like this.I never change my code...
Every senior, please help me, thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: please provide your code or configuration, thank you!